# ERROR with RETURN NEXT

Tags: postgresql

Sorry for the noob inconvenience. After some problems with destionation for result data, I get this message:
ERROR:  query "SELECT _Patient_Name, _Doc_Name, _Specialty, _Total_visit, _Total_price, _Max_price" returned 6 columns
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function list_top_patients_visit() line 35 at RETURN NEXT

when running this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION list_top_Patients_Visit()
RETURNS SETOF PatientsList AS $$

DECLARE
_Pat_Number visit.Pat_Number%type;
_Patient_Name patient.NAme%type; 
_Doc_Number doctor.Doc_Number%type;
_Doc_Name doctor.Name%type;
_Specialty doctor.Specialty%type;
_Total_visit INTEGER;
_Total_price visit.Price%type;
_Max_price visit.Price%type;
_Max_metge INTEGER;

BEGIN


FOR _Pat_Number IN (SELECT t_Pat_Number FROM (SELECT v.pat_number as t_Pat_Number, count((v.pat_number)) as t_Total_visit
FROM visit v, patient p
GROUP BY v.pat_number, p.Name
ORDER BY t_Total_visit DESC, v.pat_number
LIMIT 5) A)
    LOOP
        SELECT INTO  _Patient_Name, _Doc_Name, _Specialty, _Total_visit, _Total_price, _Max_price, _Max_metge Patient.Name  , doctor.name  , doctor.specialty  , count((visit.pat_number)) ,  sum(visit.price)  , max(visit.price)  ,  count((visit.doc_number)) as max_metge
        FROM visit, doctor, patient
        WHERE visit.pat_number=_Pat_Number and visit.doc_number=doctor.doc_number and patient.pat_number=_Pat_Number
        GROUP BY visit.doc_number, doctor.name, specialty, patient.Name
        ORDER BY max_metge DESC, visit.doc_number
        LIMIT 1;
        RETURN NEXT  _Patient_Name, _Doc_Name, _Specialty, _Total_visit, _Total_price, _Max_price;
    END LOOP;

END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

where PatientsList is

```
CREATE TYPE PatientsList AS (
t_Patient_Name VARCHAR(50) ,
t_Doc_Name VARCHAR(50) ,
t_Specialty VARCHAR(50),
t_Total_visit INTEGER,
t_Total_price DECIMAL(7,2),
t_Max_price DECIMAL(7,2));
```

I don't get to understand the meaning of the ERROR, as the TYPE is defined precisely with 6 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, PL/pgSQL insists that you explicitly combine these into a single composite value before returning them:

```
RETURN NEXT (_Patient_Name, _Doc_Name, _Specialty, _Total_visit, _Total_price, _Max_price);
```

But in your case, you can get rid of those intermediate variables and return the query result directly (no parentheses required here):

```
RETURN QUERY
  SELECT Patient.Name, doctor.name, doctor.specialty ...
```